# string with '+' sign is not displayed in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, sql-server

I have column in my database named `rate` but the datatype is string and has values like '2000+'. When I try to show this value using jQuery, why is it only showing 2000 without the '+' sign?

```
for (var j = 0; j < dtt2.length; j++) { if (dt0[i].CategoryID === dtt2[j].CategoryID) { var rate = dtt2[j].Rate; alert(rate.tostring()); $("#" + tbl).append('<tr><td>' + dtt2[j].ServiceName + '</td><td width="20%">₹ ' + rate.tostring() + '</td></tr>'); } }
```

this code is working when running on local host but when i am hosting on production the error comes string without + sign

Below is the code behind code-

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt2.Rows)
                    {
                        ServiceRateList sd = new ServiceRateList();
                        sd.ServiceDetailID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ServiceDetailID"]);
                        sd.ServiceName = dr["ServiceName"].ToString();
                        sd.CategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CategoryID"].ToString());
                        sd.CategoryName = dr["CategoryName"].ToString();
                        sd.Rate = dr["rate"].ToString();
                        bislist.Add(sd);
                }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, when you ask a question, you should share what you have tried so far. by sharing your code, we can help you to solve the problem.

Comment: Share us your Sql query and jquery code

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: share your "THIS QUERY" and "JQUERY".

Comment: for (var j = 0; j < dtt2.length; j++) {

                            if (dt0[i].CategoryID === dtt2[j].CategoryID) {
                                var rate = dtt2[j].Rate;
                                alert(rate.tostring());
                                $("#" + tbl).append('<tr><td>' + dtt2[j].ServiceName + '</td><td width="20%">₹ ' + rate.tostring() + '</td></tr>');
                            }
                        }

Comment: this code is working when running on local host but when  i am hosting on production the error comes string without + sign

Answer (score 0):

Note sure how you displaing plus sign in your JS codes.

But here work-around is to escape the plus sign by preceding it with a backslash.

```
var data = dbrawdata.replace('+', '\\+');
```

It would be good to answer your question add some line of your codes.

Comment: for (var j = 0; j < dtt2.length; j++) {

                            if (dt0[i].CategoryID === dtt2[j].CategoryID) {
                                var rate = dtt2[j].Rate;
                                alert(rate.tostring());
                                $("#" + tbl).append('<tr><td>' + dtt2[j].ServiceName + '</td><td width="20%">₹ ' + rate.tostring() + '</td></tr>');
                            }
                        }

Comment: when i used this it thows the error that                                                                                                               Uncaught TypeError: rate.tostring is not a function
    at Object.success (serviceRatelist.js?v=1551678686870:51)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: this code is working when running on local host but when  i am hosting on production the error comes string without + sign

Answer (score -1):

As i understood
Very simple,

```
var value='2000+';  
value.toString(); // => '2000+'
```

OR

```
String('2000+'); // '2000+'
```

Comment: for (var j = 0; j < dtt2.length; j++) { if (dt0[i].CategoryID === dtt2[j].CategoryID) { var rate = dtt2[j].Rate; alert(rate.tostring()); $("#" + tbl).append('<tr><td>' + dtt2[j].ServiceName + '</td><td width="20%">₹ ' + rate.tostring() + '</td></tr>'); } }

Comment: this code is working when running on local host but when i am hosting on production the error comes string without + sign